# remap with plugin text object yank not working

Tags: vim, remap

I have the textobjects-user and textobject-quotes plugin installed, using vim 8. Those let me work with multi-line strings, so I can place the cursor inside a multi-line quoted string and `diq` to delete or `yiq` to yank. Those text objects work so I know the plugin works.

I tried to define a simple key remap so I could yank the contents of a quoted string, open it in a new split, and strip excess whitespace:

```
nnoremap <leader>Q yiq<CR>:vnew<CR>p:%s/^\s\+//<CR>
```

It doesn't work. If I remove the `yiq<CR>` and do that from the keyboard, then invoke `<leader>Q` the split and paste and whitespace stripping work. If I change `yiq` to `yi'` it works.

Any reason I can't use the plugin's text objects inside a remap like this?

Comment: Presumably the plugin remaps `yiq`, but you said you want the native vim `yiq` (`noremap`), which AFAICT doesn't do anything.

Comment: No I want the plugin `yiq` behavior. It doesn't remap `y` but it does add new text objects `iq` and `aq`.

Comment: But you answered my question... `nmap` not `nnoremap`. Duh. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nore` in `nnoremap` means "don't try to execute other mappings while executing this one". It makes your mapping *non-recursive*.

Since you expressly want to use another mapping in your mapping it must be *recursive*:

```
nmap <leader>Q yiq<CR>:vnew<CR>p:%s/^\s\+//<CR>
```